# Change All Select Options Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

To clarify: I have several groups of images I want to display a group at a time. Once the user has selected an image I want the images to be cleared, and the next group displayed. I have used the ImagePicker plugin to make these images selectable.

Here is my code below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- {% block title %}{% endblock %} -->
  <title>Home</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css_files/home.css')}}">
  <link type="text/css" rel"stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css_files/image-picker.css')}}">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js_files/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')}}"></script>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js_files/image-picker.js')}}"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js_files/image-picker.min.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js_files/img_functions.js')}}"></script> 
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("select").imagepicker()
     getValue()
  });
  </script>
</head>

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block home %}Yummy Mushrooms{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form action="/home_post" mehtod="post" class="features">
    <div class="mush-attr">

      <select class="picker">
        <option id='1' class="image" data-img-src="../static/cap_shape/bell_shaped_cap.jpeg" value="b" onClick='replaceImages();'>Bell Shape</option>
        <option id='2' class="image" data-img-src='../static/cap_shape/conical_cap.jpeg' value="c">Conical Shape</option>
        <option id='3' class="image" data-img-src="../static/cap_shape/convex_cap.jpeg" value='x'>Convex Shape</option>
        <option id='4' class="image" data-img-src="../static/cap_shape/flat_cap.jpeg" value="f">Bell Shape</option>
        <option id='5' class="image" data-img-src='../static/cap_shape/knobbed_cap.jpeg' value="k">Conical Shape</option>
        <option id='6' class="image" data-img-src="../static/cap_shape/sunken_cap.jpeg" value='s'>Convex Shape</option>
      </select>


    </div>
  <!--Submit & Agreement-->
    <div class="Submit and Agreement">
      <br>
      <button id='submit-btn' type='submit'>Submit</button>
      <br>
    </div>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

I have been struggling to work with the ImagePicker object. If anyone has a lot of experience working with ImagePicker objects and could explain how to interact with it that would be great.

Otherwise, if someone could explain how they would go about changing all the `option` `data-img-src` when one option is selected. The number of options will remain constant between groups of images.

I know I can select specific elements by tag, class and id but I am not sure how to select and change them all. Below is how I was thinking of changing all of them but not sure how this would work for multiple sets of groups of images.

```
function replaceImages(){
    var el1 = document.getElementById("1")
    var el2 = document.getElementById("2")
    var el3 = document.getElementById("3")
    var el4 = document.getElementById("4")
    var el5 = document.getElementById("5")
    var el6 = document.getElementById("6")
    el1.data_img_src = "apple.png"
      .
      .
      .
};
```

Comment: you can use `el1.setAttribute('data-img-src') = 'apple.png'` to change those values. Never used ImagePicker though

Comment: I were just about to suggest the same as **Tyler Mackenzie** based on the fact I haven't use ImagePicker either.